# Is there an expression for when something happens except for a particular case?

Tags: terminology

In my language there is a mathematical expression for when a statement is true, except for a special subcase. It happens a lot in measure theory, for instance:

A property $P$ is said to hold "almost everywhere" in $X$ if there exists a set $N\subset X$ of measure zero such that $P$ holds for every point of $X$ except for maybe the points in $N$.

Say I wanted to rewrite that as a sentence in a simplified manner, removing the specifics of "points in" part and formulating it all around the set, like: "$P$ holds almost everywhere on $X$ if it holds on $X$ except for a set of measure zero"

However "except for" doesn't fit quite as good in this sentence as it does in my language. So I wonder: is there an expression in english that I can use it to rewrite this simplified version?
Please, keep in mind the measure thing is just an example, I'm not looking for a way of stating this specific expression, I want a mathematical expression to shorten the sentences like I said in this example, but that should hold for similar cases as well.

Comment: it would be simpler if you reported your case. What property do the subcases have?

Comment: I'm a native speaker of English and "except for" sounds fine in that sentence. I'm not sure I understand the concern.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you can use the prefix **co-** to describe the bigness of what remains when the exceptional set is neglected. Thus, there is *co-finite* (exceptional set is finite), *co-countable* (exceptional set is countable), *co-meager* (exceptional set is meager/first-category), *co-null* (exceptional set is "null" in some sense, often used for measure zero, but I tend to avoid it because "null" often means empty set), etc.

Another common method is to use the term **typical element** or **generic element** to describe an arbitrarily chosen non-exceptional element. However, the terminology doesn’t allow us to specify what type of smallness the exceptional set satisfies (but see the next paragraph for a way to fix this), and in practice it’s primarily used when the exceptional set is first category. See the first few paragraphs of my answer to [Generic Elements of a Set](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/96965/13130) for the likely origin of the use of *typical* in this context.

You can also use **almost every** or **typical** along with an appropriate modifier word/term to describe the bigness (I invented this many years ago as a useful shorthand -- for example, see [here](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/search?q=%22Baire%20typical%22%20Renfro) -- although it's very likely others have independently invented this wording), such as *Lebesgue almost every* or *Lebesgue typical* (exceptional set is Lebesgue measure zero), *Baire almost every* or *Baire typical* (exceptional set is first category), *porosity typical* (exceptional set is $\sigma$-porous, or maybe even porous depending on context), etc.

Consistent with the above, I’ve seen the expression $\mathcal{I}$-*typical* used when the exceptional set belongs to some [$\sigma$-ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-ideal) $\mathcal{I}$ of sets.

In the case where the exceptional set has measure zero, there is a fairly common term, namely **full measure**, or **full** $\mu$**-measure** when you want to specify the measure $\mu.$