# Most curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$ miss $\mathbb{Q}^2$

Tags: analysis, real-numbers, curves, rational-numbers

I would like a formal statement for the following fact.

> Let $\gamma$ be an analytic curve from the open interval $(-1, 1)$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. With probability $1$ (in some sense), the image of the curve does not intersect $\mathbb{Q}^2$.

How can I do it?

Comment: The support of a function is a subset of its domain. You probably meant the *image*.

Comment: I'm not a measure theory person, but have you thought of the simpler problem of $f:(-1,1)\to\mathbb R$, and $f((-1,1))$ not containing any rational with probability 1?

Comment: Probability is the wrong way to approach this. Do you know about Baire category?

Comment: @jjagmath yep that's what I meant, thanks :)

Comment: @DavidP yep that does not work, if you join two irrationals by a curve you hit rationals. But in higher dimensions the situation looks very different

Comment: @MoisheKohan I know Baire category theorem. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: *Can you please elaborate?* --- It's enough to show (for some distance function making the set of analytic curves into a complete metric space) that, for each $p \in {\mathbb Q}^2,$ most curves (in the Baire category sense; i.e. a co-meager set of curves) do not pass through $p.$ (Indeed, probably much more can be shown, namely that a co-nowhere-dense set of curves has this property, although after the next step this additional strengthening vanishes.) This is because you can then take the countable intersection **(continued)**

Comment: of the various co-meager sets (one co-meager set for each $p \in {\mathbb Q}^2)$ to get a co-meager set of curves each of which does not pass through any point of ${\mathbb Q}^2.$ See the paragraph beginning with "An interesting feature of typical properties" in my answer to [Generic Elements of a Set.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/96965/13130)

Comment: Incidentally, a similar "countable intersection" result can be used to show that "most translations" of the Cantor middle thirds set (or any perfect nowhere dense set, even one with positive measure) contain no rational numbers. For even stronger results and references, see [this 11 May 2000 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/Vj56y59Ll6k/m/8WuJkD0uVM4J). Thus, if you want a Cantor set consisting only of irrational numbers, all you need to do is "Baire-randomly translate" the Cantor middle thirds set (or any Cantor set what-so-ever)!

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Baire category argument works for continuous curve. How to adjust that to analytic curves? Do they form a closed subset of continuous curves? Also how to deal with open interval?

Comment: @183orbco3: Your questions are why I said "for some distance function making the set of analytic curves into a complete metric space" (i.e. used "some", rather than saying something more definite and specific). A standard metric is [the metric associated with uniform convergence on compact subsets](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22analytic+functions%22+%22metric%22+%22uniform+convergence%22+%22compact+subsets%22), but I don't remember much about that metric to know whether it would be suitable. However, if this metric or some other reasonably well known metric doesn't work **(continued)**

Comment: then maybe some artificially constructed metric can be found to do the job, although this would likely be a nontrivial and fairly creative task. For example, the set of Besicovitch functions is known to be a meager subset of the space of continuous functions (sup metric), and thus the Baire category method for existence doesn't work for the sup metric, but [*Where the continuous functions without unilateral derivatives are typical*](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1984-283-01/S0002-9947-1984-0735414-9/) by Malý (1984) introduces a different metric for which the method does work.