# Examples of dense $G_\delta$ sets in $L^p$ spaces

Tags: lp-spaces, baire-category

The Baire Category Theorem states that the countable intersections of open dense subsets of a complete metric space (called dense $G_\delta$ sets) are dense. Any open set is $G_\delta$, so any dense open set is dense $G_\delta$.

I know that the set of irrational numbers is an example of a dense $G_\delta$ set in $\mathbb{R}$ that is not open.

I am wondering if there are examples of non-open dense $G_\delta$ sets in function spaces such as $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $\mathcal{C}^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and $W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ endowed with their usual norms.

Comment: See [*Applications of the Baire category theorem*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/real-analysis-exchange/volume-23/issue-2/Applications-of-the-Baire-Category-Theorem/rae/1337001353.full) by Jones (1997-1998) AND [Your favourite application of the Baire Category Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/165696/13130) AND [Classic applications of Baire category theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/129666/15780). What follows are some randomly selected references that you can use to expand your search. For $L^p$ spaces **(continued)**

Comment: see [Quade 1935](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1935-41-02/S0002-9904-1935-06013-6/) AND [Oxtoby 1937](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1937-43-04/S0002-9904-1937-06525-6/) AND [Rother 1993](https://zbmath.org/0805.26007) AND [Wingren 1999](https://zbmath.org/1010.54034). For the space of bounded derivatives see [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/112133/13130). For differentiability properties of continuous functions see [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/96965/13130). **(continued)**

Comment: For nowhere analytic $C^{\infty}$ functions see section IV [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161009194815/http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=387148) and section IV [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161009194829/http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=387149). For topological knot theory see [Milnor 1964](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm54/fm54126.pdf). For topological dynamics see [Akin/Hurley/Kennedy 2003](https://bookstore.ams.org/view?ProductCode=MEMO/164/783). **(continued)**

Comment: For mathematical logic see [Suzuki 1970](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm67/fm6719.pdf) AND [Myhill 1960](https://msp.org/pjm/1961/11-4/pjm-v11-n4-p29-s.pdf). For ODEs and PDEs see [Wehausen 1945](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1945-51-02/S0002-9904-1945-08284-6/) AND [Alexiewicz/Orlicz 1955-1956](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm15/sm15122.pdf) AND [Lasota/Yorke 1973](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022039673900272). **(continued)**

Comment: For "Riemann-rearrangemnt" series results see [here](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/_QAPMEknGiA/m/alStnJOqlq4J). For trigonometric series convergence results see [Kahane 2000](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02791536). For harmonic analysis see [Körner 2009](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~twk/Baire.pdf). For some topological dimension results see [Kuratowski 1980](https://www.google.com/search?q=10.1216%2FRMJ-1980-10-1-25). For ergodic theory see [Choksi/Prasad 1983](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0099849).

Comment: Basically, just google (besides google, use Zbl archive or Math. Reviews -- if you have access -- or google scholar or google books) things like "generic" or "typical" or "Baire category" along with the topic/space you are interested in, and you should come up with something.

Comment: Here's a conference publication by MSE's [Robert Israel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8508/robert-israel) that involves Baire category in an area not known for its use -- [*Some Generic Results in Mathematical Physics*](http://math-mprf.org/journal/articles/id1023/) (2004).